# How to tell when a group of events have completed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an engine, and it has a method `tick` that gets called over and over on a `timeout`. In the tick function I have calls to other functions before the `timeout` calls itself again. These functions are basically the exact same thing only they call a different method on the object.

I would like to change these functions from a loop to a `dispatchEvent`, and execute a custom event. The issues I face is that I would like to know when the event has been fished on the group. For example when I run `start()` I would like to know when all the start methods have completed or when I run `update()` know when all the update methods have completed.

I would like to do this because I want all objects to run the method group together, and not at their own convenience. So for example say I have `obj1` and `obj2` I don't want `obj1` to be running it's start method while `obj2` is already running its `update` method. I want them all to run the same methods at the same time.

I get that effect while looping through the objects, but it runs synchronously, and not asynchronously.

```
class Engine {
    private static objects = [];
    public constructor() {
        setTimeout(tick.bind(this), 0);
    }
    public tick() {
        start();
        update();
        lateUpdate();
        // etc.
        setTimeout(tick.bind(this), 0);
    }
    public update() {
        objects.forEach(object => {
            if(typeof object['update'] == 'function') {
                object['update']();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Taking that example, I will modify it to what I would like to do (se the update method):

```
class Engine {
    private static objects = [];
    public constructor() {
        setTimeout(tick.bind(this), 0);
    }
    public tick() {
        start();
        update();
        lateUpdate();
        // etc.
        setTimeout(tick.bind(this), 0);
    }
    public update() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('update'));
        // Stop here and wait until all events finish.
        // Once all events finish on all objects, continue on
    }
}
```

Here is a component class that gets added to each object:

```
class AutoMove extends Canvas.Behavior {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.speed = 3;
    }
    update() {
        // translate just add (this.x += x, and this.y += y) to the items current position
        this.transform.translate(this.speed, 0);
    }
}
```

My actual update call looks something like this (i simplified it above):

```
update() {
    this.objects.forEach(object => {
        object.components.forEach(comp => {
            if(typeof comp['update'] == 'function') {
                // This calls the update in the above component
                comp['update'](); 
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Once I have about 500 - 600 objects, the objects start moving from left to right slower and slower as the number of objects grow it gets slower. I currently haven't added the logic to not render items out of view, so that could be the issue also.

objects are also created on an `setInterval` for testing.

Comment: why do you want to change to an event based system? What improvement/gain do you expect from that change?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I believe I will gain the ability to run the methods on the objects async instead of sync, which will allow a group of methods to finish running their tasks a few milliseconds/seconds faster.

Comment: I doubt that. It depends on what the methods actually do. Since you're running them synchronous now, I'd doubt that they perform anything async *(like loading a file, or doing some requests, etc.)*. And because JS is single threaded it can not run two pieces of code at the same time. So, unless you're doing something async in these functions, you'll no get faster but on the contrary inplies the Event-system *(a little bit)* more work to do that just a plain function call. Do you have actual performance problems you need to fix, or are you just trying to optimize/improve something?

Comment: What I am doing is using a canvas, and I have tested creating objects on the left side of the screen and moving them to the right side of the screen. With lots of items it slows down, and has trouble keeping up sometimes and everything moves slowly.

Comment: Can you show that code. This sounds like to many render cycles. First of all, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` this runs your canvas-updates in sync with the native render-cycle and therefore avoids/reduces additional render-cycles caused by your code. Second you could spread the actions on multiple "frames": `start(){ /*...*/ requestAnimationFrame(update) }` `update(){ /*...*/ requestAnimationFrame(lateUpdate) }` `lateUpdate(){ /*...*/ requestAnimationFrame(start) }` so they run in a cycle. You might have to modify how you split the code to fit your needs.

Comment: I am using both `setTimeout` (for the logic) and `requestAnimationFrame` (for the rendering) I will update question (one moment).

Comment: Okay I have updated the question with more code.